# How can I set series data dynamically in a Highcharts polar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts polar chart that displays my data fine inline, but my app's workflow requires the data to be loaded separately from the chart config.  Other chart types seem to work fine when I use `chart.series[0].setData(mySeriesData)` but the polar chart looks goofy.  Other than the series data, the chart configuration is identical across both charts. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a fiddle with my example: https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/br3cz4vf/

[image]

My chart:

```
const config = {
  "chart": {
    "polar": true,
    parallelCoordinates: true,
    parallelAxes: {
      gridLineWidth: 0,
    },    
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "one",
      "type": "line",
    },
    {
      "name": "two",
      "type": "line",
    },
  ],
  "title": { "text": "" },
  "xAxis": {
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "labels": {
      "enabled": true,
    },
    categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
    type: 'category'
  },
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "max": 10,
      "min": -10,
    },
    {
      "max": 450,
      "min": 300,
    },
    {
      "max": 12,
      "min": 1,
    },
    {
      "max": 12,
      "min": 2,
    },
    {
      "max": 12,
      "min": 2,
    }
  ],
};


// Set up first chart with inline data specified in the series
const config1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
config1.title.text = "in-line data shows ok"
config1.series[0].data = data1;
config1.series[1].data = data2;
const chart1 = Highcharts.chart(containerId, config1);

// Set up second chart with no initial data...
const config2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
config2.title.text = "Why doesn't dynamic data loading work?"
const chart2 = Highcharts.chart(containerId2, config2);

// ... but try to dynamically load datasets into series
chart2.series[0].setData(data1);
chart2.series[1].setData(data2);
chart2.redraw();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Highcharts Github:

> In the current implementation, the chart is creating the parallel axes
> only on chart init. This is dictated by performance: a parallel chart,
> in general, is used with a lot of data. Watching changes in the
> dataset (number of categories etc.) would cost quite a lot of
> performance and we assumed it would be easier and faster to recreate
> the chart when we really need it.

As a solution, you can create a chart when data is received or use `chart.update`:

```
chart2.update({
    series: [{
        data: data1
    }, {
        data: data2
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tnhy9a1u/

**Github issue:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16380

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This makes sense, even though my particular charts aren't using a lot of data.  I think the chart update workaround will be just fine.